# How get top center and bottom center position point from SpriteRenderer Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get from the SpriteRenderer these positions from the screenshot, this is the top center point and the bottom center point to create objects at these positions, so I need the global position of these points.

[image]

I already tried to use Bounds, but they did not give me the result I needed, they show the wrong center, min and max positions, or rather they were created in other places. Maybe I misunderstood something? The search logic is written in a different object, and the SpriteRenderer is on a different object,

```
        Bounds spriteBounds = SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds;

        _centerPointValue = spriteBounds.center;
        _rightUpPointValue = spriteBounds.max;
        _leftBottomPointValue = spriteBounds.min;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SpriteRenderer.bounds` instead?

Comment: Surely rightup is top right and leftbottom being bottom left you want the middle of those at the top and the middle at the bottom you can calculate both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the correct

- Center
- BottomLeft
- TopRight

calculating your desired

- BottomCenter
- TopCenter

should be trivial:

```
var bottomCenter = _rightUpPointValue;
bottomCenter.x = _centerPointValue.x;

var topCenter = _rightUpPointValue;
topCenter.x = _centerPointValue.x;
```

---

**tl;dr:** Instead of `SpriteRenderer.sprite.bounds` use `SpriteRenderer.bounds`

---

Actually using those works just fine for me **IF**

- The renderer isn't anyhow scaled
- The renderer isn't anyhow moved
- The renderer is using `Draw Mode = simple`

In this case you *could* use the `Sprite.bounds` (shouldn't though - see below)

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private class NamedPosition
    {
        public NamedPosition(Vector2 position, string label)
        {
            Position = position;
            Label = label;
        }

        public Vector2 Position { get; }
        public string Label { get; }
    }

    public GameObject prefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        var spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        var bounds = spriteRender.sprite.bounds;

        var positions = new List<NamedPosition>();

        var center = bounds.center;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(center, nameof(center)));
        
        var topRight = bounds.max;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(topRight, nameof(topRight)));
        
        var bottomLeft = bounds.min;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(bottomLeft, nameof(bottomLeft)));
        
        var topCenter = topRight;
        topCenter.x = center.x;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(topCenter, nameof(topCenter)));
        
        var bottomCenter = bottomLeft;
        bottomCenter.x = center.x;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(bottomCenter, nameof(bottomCenter)));

        foreach (var namedPosition in positions)
        {
            var instance = Instantiate(prefab, namedPosition.Position, quaternion.identity);
            instance.name = namedPosition.Label;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

If this is not the case (probably in the most use cases) you rather want to use the [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) instead.

This kind of behaves the same as the difference between `Mesh.bounds` and `Renderer.bounds`.

The `Mesh.bounds` and `Sprite.bounds` is basically the local space bounds without applying the transforms while the `Renderer.bounds` is the **actual bounds** in your scene.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private class NamedPosition
    {
        public NamedPosition(Vector2 position, string label)
        {
            Position = position;
            Label = label;
        }

        public Vector2 Position { get; }
        public string Label { get; }
    }

    public GameObject prefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        var spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        var bounds = spriteRender.bounds;

        var positions = new List<NamedPosition>();

        var center = bounds.center;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(center, nameof(center)));
        
        var topRight = bounds.max;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(topRight, nameof(topRight)));
        
        var bottomLeft = bounds.min;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(bottomLeft, nameof(bottomLeft)));
        
        var topCenter = topRight;
        topCenter.x = center.x;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(topCenter, nameof(topCenter)));
        
        var bottomCenter = bottomLeft;
        bottomCenter.x = center.x;
        positions.Add(new NamedPosition(bottomCenter, nameof(bottomCenter)));

        foreach (var namedPosition in positions)
        {
            var instance = Instantiate(prefab, namedPosition.Position, quaternion.identity);
            instance.name = namedPosition.Label;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool answer, thanks, I understand how it works! And I realized my mistake. And I have another question, how did you make the GIF animation?)

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Glad to help! And https://www.screentogif.com ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have imported the sprite into unity, and added it to a SpriteRenderer:

[imported image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmMJ7.png)

I have also created 2 markers, topMarker and bottomMarker, those are a couple of gameObjects and I’m pretending to take their Transforms and position’em on the selected bounds (center-top and center-bottom of the sprite rendered).

As we can see, there are 3 relevant transforms: 1 for SpriteRenderer, and 2 for our markers.
So we can get the center of the sprite renderer, if we get the component and then access to it’s transform:

```
SpriteRenderer sprite;
```

…

```
sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

…

```
Debug.Log("POSITION: " + sprite.transform.position);
```

Once we got this, we can get the max bounds from the sprite renderer:

```
Debug.Log("Center Top: " + (sprite.transform.position.y + sprite.bounds.max.y));
```

And now we can test it positioning our markers automatically:

```
topMarker.position = sprite.transform.position + new Vector3(0,sprite.bounds.max.y,0);
bottomMarker.position = sprite.transform.position + new Vector3(0,-sprite.bounds.max.y,0);
```

Then, if we hit play, we can see our markers positioning on said point:

[markers moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R9cN.png)

Here’s the code so you can try it and understand the logic behind this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class getBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    SpriteRenderer sprite;
 
    [SerializeField]
    Transform topMarker, bottomMarker;
 
    void Start()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
       
        Debug.Log("INFO:");
        Debug.Log("-------------------------");
        Debug.Log("POSITION: " + sprite.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("BOUNDS: " + sprite.bounds);
        Debug.Log("Center Top: " + (sprite.transform.position.y + sprite.bounds.max.y));
 
        topMarker.position = sprite.transform.position + new Vector3(0,sprite.bounds.max.y,0);
        bottomMarker.position = sprite.transform.position + new Vector3(0,-sprite.bounds.max.y,0);
    }
}
```